# Missing MACHTYPE in makefile

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

My makefile has the following two lines.

```
$(MACHTYPE)/jkweb.a: $(O) $(MACHTYPE)
        ar rcus $(MACHTYPE)/jkweb.a $(O)
```

When I echo I can see MACHTYPE is `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`. I already have the `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` directory in the current directory. But when I type make, it says `ar: /jkweb.a: Permission denied` which is supposed to be `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/jkweb.a`.

Why is the MACHTYPE missing?

P.S.
The software is [Blat](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~kent/src/). The [mailing list](https://lists.soe.ucsc.edu/pipermail/genome/2008-June/016592.html) suggests change MACHTYPE to x86_64.

```
include ../inc/common.mk


O = aliType.o annoColumn.o annoFilter.o annoFormatter.o annoFormatTab.o \
    annoGrator.o annoGratorQuery.o annoOption.o annoRow.o annoStreamer.o annoStreamVcf.o \
    apacheLog.o asParse.o axt.o axtAffine.o bamFile.o base64.o \
    basicBed.o bbiRead.o bbiWrite.o bigBed.o binRange.o bits.o \
    blastOut.o blastParse.o boxClump.o boxLump.o bPlusTree.o \
    bwgCreate.o bwgQuery.o bwgValsOnChrom.o \
    cda.o chain.o chainBlock.o chainConnect.o chainToAxt.o chainToPsl.o \
    cheapcgi.o cirTree.o codebias.o colHash.o common.o correlate.o crTree.o \
    dgRange.o diGraph.o dlist.o dnaLoad.o dnaMarkov.o dnaMotif.o dnaseq.o \
    dnautil.o dsPrint.o dtdParse.o dystring.o \
    emblParse.o errCatch.o errabort.o \
    fa.o ffAli.o ffScore.o filePath.o fixColor.o flydna.o fof.o \
    font/mgCourier10.o font/mgCourier12.o font/mgCourier14.o font/mgCourier18.o \
    font/mgCourier24.o font/mgCourier34.o font/mgCourier8.o font/mgHelvetica10.o \
    font/mgHelvetica12.o font/mgHelvetica14.o font/mgHelvetica18.o font/mgHelvetica24.o \
    font/mgHelvetica34.o font/mgHelvetica8.o font/mgHelveticaBold10.o font/mgHelveticaBold12.o \
    font/mgHelveticaBold14.o font/mgHelveticaBold18.o font/mgHelveticaBold24.o \
    font/mgHelveticaBold34.o font/mgHelveticaBold8.o font/mgSixhi6.o font/mgSail8.o \
    font/mgTimes10.o font/mgTimes12.o font/mgTimes14.o font/mgTimes18.o \
    font/mgTimes24.o font/mgTimes34.o font/mgTimes8.o font/mgMenlo12.o \
    fuzzyShow.o \
    gapCalc.o gdf.o gemfont.o genomeRangeTree.o \
    gfNet.o gff.o gff3.o gfxPoly.o gifLabel.o \
    hacTree.o hash.o histogram.o hmmPfamParse.o hmmstats.o htmlPage.o htmshell.o \
    https.o intExp.o intValTree.o internet.o itsa.o iupac.o \
    jointalign.o jpegSize.o keys.o knetUdc.o kxTok.o linefile.o lineFileOnBigBed.o localmem.o log.o \
    maf.o mafFromAxt.o mafScore.o md5.o memalloc.o memgfx.o metaWig.o mgCircle.o \
    mgPolygon.o mime.o net.o nib.o nibTwo.o nt4.o numObscure.o \
    obscure.o oldGff.o oligoTm.o options.o osunix.o pairHmm.o peakCluster.o \
    phyloTree.o pipeline.o portimpl.o pngwrite.o psGfx.o psPoly.o pscmGfx.o \
    psl.o pslGenoShow.o pslShow.o pslTbl.o pslTransMap.o pthreadWrap.o \
    qa.o quickHeap.o quotedP.o \
    ra.o rainbow.o rbTree.o rangeTree.o regexHelper.o repMask.o \
    rle.o rnautil.o rqlEval.o rqlParse.o rudp.o \
    scoreWindow.o seg.o seqOut.o seqStats.o servBrcMcw.o servCrunx.o \
    servcis.o servcl.o servmsII.o servpws.o shaRes.o slog.o snof.o \
    snofmake.o snofsig.o spaceSaver.o spacedColumn.o spacedSeed.o \
    splatAli.o sqlList.o sqlNum.o subText.o sufa.o sufx.o synQueue.o \
    tabRow.o textOut.o tokenizer.o trix.o twoBit.o \
    udc.o vcf.o vGfx.o vPng.o verbose.o \
    wildcmp.o wormdna.o \
    xAli.o xa.o xap.o xenshow.o xmlEscape.o xp.o zlibFace.o

$(MACHTYPE)/jkweb.a: $(O) $(MACHTYPE)
    ar rcus $(MACHTYPE)/jkweb.a $(O)

$(MACHTYPE):
    mkdir $(MACHTYPE)

test:
    cd tests && ${MAKE} test

clean:
    rm -f ${O} $(MACHTYPE)/jkweb.a
    cd tests && ${MAKE} clean

tags:
    etags ../inc/*.h ../lib/*.h ../lib/*.c  ../hg/inc/*.h ../hg/lib/*.h ../hg/lib/*.c ../hg/hgTracks/*.c ../hg/hgc/*.c ../hg/hgTrackUi/*.c
```

Comment: Could you please show us the whole makefile?

Comment: Did you `export` the `MACHTYPE` variable in your shell?

Comment: When you say that you echo MACHTYPE, do you mean that you do it within the makefile, or from the command line?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did it in command line. Can I do that in makefile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's try an experiment:

1) check the shell: `echo $SHELL`. (I expect bash.)

2) check the variable: `set | grep MACHTYPE` (I expect "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".)

3) check the variable again: `printenv | grep MACHTYPE` (I expect nothing, no output.)

4) At the top of the makefile add the line `$(info MACHTYPE is $(MACHTYPE))` and run `make`. (I expect "MACHTYPE is ", followed by failure.)

5) Knock wood and run `make MACHTYPE=$MACHTYPE`.

**EDIT:**
Good! The problem is that the variable `MACHTYPE` is in your shell as a *local* variable (which is not passed to a process like `make`), not as an *environmental* variable (which would be). So you can run Make as above, `make MACHTYPE=$MACHTYPE`, or turn MACHTYPE into an environmental variable:

```
export MACHTYPE
make
```

(Correction thanks to Reinier Torenbeek.)

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what you expect.

Comment: Nice answer. One minor improvement: the `export` does not require reassignment of the value to the variable. In this scenario, it should be sufficient to just do `export MACHTYPE`.

Answer (score 0):

I have this:

```
MACHTYPE:=$(shell set | grep ^MACHTYPE= | sed s-.*=--)
```